# Generate pdf using stream in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to generate pdf and display inside any Div, I am getting binary data from server but when I try to convert that stream it says failed to load pdf. 
I googled it and saw response of many people saying use responseType: 'arraybuffer' but I am getting object from server and extracting binary from it so I can't use it, though I tried with this approach as well but it didn't work.
Here is my controller code:

```
 correspondenceService.getCorrespondenceDocument(id).$promise.then(function (data) {
                var file = new Blob([(data[0].documentBytes)], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                vm.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
                window.open(fileURL);

            }, function (reason) { });
        }
```

**This is Service:**

```
 getCorrespondenceDocument: function (correspondenceId) {
                return $resource(correspondenceUrl + "getCorrespondenceDocuments").query({ correspondenceId: correspondenceId });
            }
```

**and this is my webApi:**

```
  [Route("getCorrespondenceDocuments")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Document>> GetCorrespondenceDocumentsAsync(int correspondenceId)
        {
            var documents = await _correspondenceFacade.GetCorrespondenceDocumentDetailsAsync(correspondenceId);
            return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Document>>(documents);
        }
```

Trying to display like this on View:

Please let me know where I am doing mistake. Many thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to do it. Problem is I was passing 3 parameters in $http.get(), now I am passing 2 parameters only.

```
 getCorrespondenceDocuments: function (correspondenceId) {
            return $http.get(correspondenceUrl + 'getCorrespondenceDocuments' + '?correspondenceId=' + correspondenceId, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).then(function (response) {
                return response;
            });
        }
```

Though I don't like to pass any parameter using this "?" and specifying id but I couldn't find any solution to this problem.
Many thanks guys for going through my post.
Regards,
Vivek